# ASP Site - Updating Dlls on Change

Tags: asp.net, dll, build

When I make a change to the a aspx.cs page in my website and then build I notice that none of the `dll`s in the Bin folder are updated, the only dlls I can see in there are the references the web app uses. I want to bring across this one change rather than redeploy the whole site so where are the changes being saved?

I've tried various things like build solution, rebuild solution, build website, rebuild web site.

Is it possible my dll is being sent elsewhere? How would I go about finding out where?

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, on root project node, right-click and select Properties. Click on the "Build" tab and look under "Output" section. Here you will see the actual output path and can change it to your bin folder.

Comment: Within my solution I don't have a project, all I have is a Web Site which contains all the content. Right clicking this gives me an option for Property Window or Property Pages. Within Property Pages there is a Build page but this doesn't have an Output section.

Comment: I never use the website project template. My recommendation is to switch to the Web Application project.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, on root project node, right-click and try to Clean solution and then again build whole solution.